# How to place WSGI script mysql query into a ' function '

Tags: python, function, mod-wsgi, wsgi, mysql-python

Because i am new and also because there isn't much to work with on google search for WSGI.. ı need to figure out how to place the mysql query below into a function in WSGI script.

here is the current non function version.

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",
                        user = "a",
                        passwd = "",
                        db = "a")
cursor = conn.cursor ()
cursor.execute ("select * from `01` where id in (1) limit 1")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close ()
conn.close ()

aaa = rows[0][1]

def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('content-type', 'text/html')])
    yield aaa
```

simply let me know how to place that mysql query into a function then call it from a function.. i know how to work with functions in PHP but not much experience in WSGI

Answer (score 0):

Setup code should be ran once, not for each query, so that stays at the top:

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect(
    host   = "localhost",
    db     = "a"
    user   = "a",
    passwd = "",
)
```

Query-specific code goes inside a `def` and gets a name:

```
def query():
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("select * from `01` where id in (1) limit 1")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close ()

    return rows
```

Cleanup code, like startup code, runs once -- but at the end:

```
conn.close()
```

And the function is invoked like this:

```
results = query()
```

Comment: The creation of the connection cannot be at global scope of the module if the WSGI application is being deployed on a multithreading WSGI server. This is because concurrent requests will fight over the use of the same connection.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton So make a method that returns the connection for the current thread (either creating it or using a cached version). Then the `query()` can do `conn = current_connection()` or something like that as its first step, and then just use that for the rest of the method.

Comment: results are still being cached although i started using the example above.

Comment: @Graham Dumpleton would you happen to have some working example ? perhaps on your blog ?

Comment: Although i am not yet certain.. it looks like i might have solved the problem by switching to _mysql .. in an old script of mine i had import _mysql rather than import MySQLdb .. i am testing it.. working without caching so far...